# Cancel a task execution in a thread and remove a task from a queue

Tags: python, multithreading

A Python application I'm developing watches for a folder and uploads certain new or changed files to a server. As a task queue I'm using [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) module and a pool of worker threads.

Sometimes during an upload a file changes and the upload needs to be canceled and started all over.

I know how to stop thread execution with [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects), but how do I remove or move around a task in Queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to mark the instance you've loaded into the `Queue` as cancelled:

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.cancelled = False
        self.data = data

    def cancel(self):
        self.cancelled = True

q = Queue.Queue()
t = Task("some data to put in the queue")
q.put(t)

# Later
t.cancel()
```

Then in your consuming thread:

```
task = q.get()
if task.cancelled:
  # Skip it
else:
  # handle it.
```

It is also possible to directly interact with the `deque` that the `Queue` uses internally, provided you acquire the internal mutex used to synchronized access to the `Queue`:

```
>>> import Queue
>>> q = Queue.Queue()
>>> q.put("a")
>>> q.put("b")
>>> q.put("c")
>>> q.put("d")
>>> q.queue[2]
'c'
>>> q.queue[3]
'd'
>>> with q.mutex:  # Always acquire the lock first in actual usage
...   q.queue[3]
... 
'd'
```

While this should work, messing with the internals of the `Queue` isn't recommended, and could break across Python versions if the implementation of `Queue` changes. Also, keep in mind that operations other than `append`/`appendleft` and `pop`/`popleft` on `deque` objects do not perform as well as they do on `list` instances; even something as simple as `__getitem__` is `O(n)`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it is possible to change the data already put to Queue from the sender thread. Is it thread-safe?

Comment: @Warwick as long as you're just setting one attribute from the sender thread, and reading that attribute from the consumer, yes. Both setting and reading an attribute are atomic in CPython, and because of the GIL there's no way both operations could run in parallel. One will always start and complete before the other.